# how to hide all inactive/disable steps in magento checkout page

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

I want to show only one step at a time on magento checkout page and when a customer will click on continue button then next step should appear and remaining all steps should be hide. As you can see in the picture, here checkout method is active and remaining steps are just disable so here i want all disable step should be hide not just to keep as disable. there is two js file also been included accordion.js and opcheckout.js. I tried a lot to achieve the same thing but I couldn't not achieve So please some one help me, please !! 
[image: Here is screenshot of checkout page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `checkout/onepage.phtml` you have a line that generates `li`'s with different classes given they are sections that are allowed or not.

I'm not a pro in CSS but I suggest you `display:none` the class `section` (which all tabs have) and `display:block` the tabs that have the classes `section` and `allow`. Not sure how this would work in CSS but you see the idea.

Comment: great work.. it works for me ..thanks, thanks a lot !!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you! But could you please mark this answer as accepted for your question not to pop up in the future as it has been resolved? Thanks